# How I can fetch array from function in OO PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I started playing with OO PHP. I want to retrieve some data from my DB using function and then fetch_array should enable me to "unpack" array. ( nice loop for each and so on). How should I apprach this problem in object oriented programming

```
public static function find_by_sql($sql="") 
{
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) 
    {
        $something $something
    }
    return $something $something;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note. Using `static` methods is *not* really OOP sir.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question well, the function you're looking for is [PDO's fetchObject function](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) .

Answer (score 0):

Is the whole question what to do with the "something something" parts?

```
$records = array();
while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) 
{
    $records[] = $row;
}
return $records;
```